# Check if given string id is present in array of objectId mongo aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a table admin which has a field `groupId` which is an array of ids from table group,
eg:

```
groupId = [
  ObjectId("12344555"),
  ObjectId("1544555"),
  ObjectId("1239875")
]
```

now while querying a string `groupId` will be sent and I need to check if it is in the `groupId` of the admin so if I send `12344555` as query param then I need true and if I send `12344556` I need false as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

- If you try to query for only on id:

```
const result = await collection.find({groupId: ObjectId('12344555')})
```

- For multiple id:

```
const result = await collection.find({groupId: {$in: [ObjectId('12344555'), ObjectId('1544555')]}})
```

- For boolean result:

```
if (result.length) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you just need to know if the `id` is present in the `array`, you can use the `countDocument` operation

```
const count = await Model.countDocument({'groupId':mongoose.Types.ObjectId('12344555')});
```

If `id` is not present the count returns `0`